# Using Modal Forms - Relative paths don't work

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I'm using the Modal Forms module to provide Modal Login and Register Forms across my site. Unfortunately it only seems to work if I access the link from a page which is one deep from the host folder. i.e.

- Localhost/drupal/myform - Works
- Localhost/drupal/node/31 - Doesn't Work

The error that throws says that

`/drupal/node/modal_forms/ajax/login` can't be found. Which is correct because the login form is kept at:

`/drupal/modal_forms/ajax/login`

It's adding the relative path on the end of the current page path.

A. Has anyone come across or solved this before?

IF NOT:

B. I think the code path is being pulled from hook_menu:

```
function modal_forms_menu() {
    $items['modal_forms/%ctools_js/login'] = array(
      'title' => 'Log in',
      'page callback' => 'modal_forms_login',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
```

I tried changing the link to  a direct path (not relative), but this doesn't do anything. What should I be trying to change to get the path to either load from `/drupal/` each time or become direct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to how I implemented the modal forms. I'd put the following path:
"modal_forms/%ctools_js/login" in my menu links.

Changing this to an absolute rather than relative path solved the problem.